# Dangerous or common username in for user vanity url

Tags: security

I'm changing my app to allow vanity user url:

```
http://domain.com/username
```

I am trying to find out what are the common names that should be prevented from the user to register, such as: phpmyadmin, password, username, about, contact, support, etc.

Best if there is a list available, but I haven't been able to find one.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not a subdomain e.g. `http://username.domain.com`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could allow any name as long as it doesn't conflict with another page on your site. You may want to consider the following just to prevent such conflicts:

```
http://domain.com/user/username
```

That way you could still use

```
http://domain.com/about
http://domain.com/contact
```

for your own URLs.

Comment: Hmm, I was considering that too. Now that it seems to give me lots of trouble when not including `/user/`, I really think I should include it. Thanks.